# vb.net layering of controls not working properly

Tags: vb.net, controls, layer

I simply want to add three controls to my form. The first two show up, but the third does not. I do not understand why this behavior is happening. I have tried using .bringToFront(), but I end up with the same results. I also tried using Me.controls.setChildIndex() but that does not help either.

I am at a loss. I must be doing something wrong. Please help.

Thanks.

This is my code:

```
' Add the label
' ------------------
  Dim menu_label As New Label
  menu_label.Text = "Menu"
  menu_label.Location = New Point(50, 20)
  menu_label.Width = 50
  menu_label.Font = New Font(main_font, main_font_size, FontStyle.Regular)
  menu_label.ForeColor = Color.White
  Me.Controls.Add(menu_label)

' create the image
' ---------------
  Dim logo As New PictureBox
  Dim logo_image As Image
  logo_image = My.Resources.logo
  logo.Image = logo_image
  logo.Width = 30
  logo.Height = 30
  logo.Left = 5
  logo.Top = 0
  Me.Controls.Add(logo)

' add a line
' ----------
  Dim line As New Panel
  line.Height = 1
  line.Width = Me.Width
  line.BackColor = Color.Red
  line.Location = New Point(0, 32)
  Me.Controls.Add(line)


' end code
' ---------------------------------
```

Only the first two items show up no matter which order I put them in. So I either get just the logo and the menu label, or just the logo and the line, or just the line and the menu label. It's nuts!

So I tried:

```
Me.Controls.SetChildIndex(logo, 0)
Me.Controls.SetChildIndex(menu_label, 1)
Me.Controls.SetChildIndex(line, 2)
```

Whichever item gets assigned to level 2 never shows up.

Comment: I tried your code, the first part, in the load event and saw all three items.  I took the default for the font.

Comment: Have a look at the indexes of all the relevant controls before and after each set. I suspect they are getting bumped about after each change. If I were you I'd create a user control, and wrap these three up in it.

Answer (score 0):

I also tested and it worked fine for me.  Changed the form backcolor to black so you can see the results better:

[image: Layout Troubleshooting Test]

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' Add the label
    ' ------------------
    Dim menu_label As New Label
    menu_label.Text = "Menu"
    menu_label.Location = New Point(50, 20)
    menu_label.Width = 50
    'menu_label.Font = New Font(main_font, main_font_size, FontStyle.Regular)
    menu_label.ForeColor = Color.White
    Me.Controls.Add(menu_label)

    ' create the image
    ' ---------------
    Dim logo As New PictureBox
    Dim logo_image As Image
    'logo_image = My.Resources.logo
    'logo.Image = logo_image
    logo.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    logo.Width = 30
    logo.Height = 30
    logo.Left = 5
    logo.Top = 0
    Me.Controls.Add(logo)

    ' add a line
    ' ----------
    Dim line As New Panel
    line.Height = 1
    line.Width = Me.Width
    line.BackColor = Color.Red
    line.Location = New Point(0, 32)
    Me.Controls.Add(line)

    Me.BackColor = Color.Black
End Sub
```

What else is on your form?  Perhaps you could post a screenshot?

Comment: Where do you put the "I'm an idiot" post? I finally figured out what I was doing. After the form loads, I have a Sub that removes all of the controls but the first two, then adds them back after reading some parameters. I totally forgot that was going on. Sorry. But maybe I should learn to add a user control like Tony Said. I'll have to learn how to do that. So maybe it wasn't all for nothing. Thanks.

Comment: It happens...glad you figured it out.  ;)